# Updating globals in circular import

Tags: python, circular-dependency, global

Let me begin that I'm aware that use of globals like this is bad, but I'm unfortunately constrained by forces outside of my control.

I have two files:

a.py:

```
x = {}
from b import *

def main():
  global x
  x[0] = 'hello'
  foo()
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

b.py:

```
import a as my_a


def foo():
  print(my_a.x)
```

I want executing `$python a.py` to print out for me the updated dict, but right now it only provides the empty dict.

Is there any way I can simply modify this code so that `foo()` to see the updated changes to `a.py`?  I would also prefer to avoid frequent reimporting.  Note that in practice `b.py` is actually a very long file, and I also cannot change its function definitions to add more arguments.

Comment: It is very important to understand that your `global` statement does nothing useful in the `main` function

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Noted.  This was stripped down from more complex code and I copied that over, it could be removed for this example.

Comment: `a.py` is used to create *two* modules, `__main__` and `a`. Despite coming from the same code, they are distinct, so `my_a.x` does not reference the same object as `__main__.x` (which is what `__main__.main()` updates.)

Comment: Thank you, @chepner, that is very helpful to understand.  Is there any way I can modify a's values from within main?  Should I break main off into a third file that imports a.py?

Comment: I would definitely separate `a.py` into two files. It could be as simply as simply stripping the `if` block from `a.py`, then defining `main.py` as just importing `a` and calling `a.main()`.

Comment: And while you are at it, don't use `from b import *`. Just import `b` and use `b.foo` where necessary.

Comment: Thank you.  I got my real (non-MRE) code working, and your insight regarding main being its own module was what made it work.  I never realized.learned that in 10 years of python.  If you post an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you simply do something like:

### a.py:

```
from b import foo

x = {}


def main():
    # global x
    x[0] = 'hello'
    foo(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### b.py:

```
def foo(val):
    print(val)
```

Thus you get rid of the circular import.
Note that from `b import *` is bad practice and can lead to [namespace pollution](https://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces/). In this example we import only the stuff we need with: `from b import foo`

Comment: Or even better just `import b` and use `b.foo()`

Comment: My goal is to not modify any of the functions that already exist in b.py.  I am trying to treat b.py as much as an API as possible and there are some functions that I cannot modify (also b.py is very long).  I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: @balmy that still does not work.  Nothing is updated in my_a.